# Metasearch - Remove duplicated pictures with different resolution - improving on current approach

Tags: algorithm, search, heuristics

Assume that **one picture** with **different resolutions** from **one host** has **more than one** copies.

At the metasearcher stage, I want to check if the 2 pictures have the **same names**, but **not trivial names** (such as image.jpg, photo.jpg ...). In this case, I want to include only the picture with higher resolution.

Example:
search for "city"

https://znews-photo.zadn.vn/w480/Uploaded/lerl/2017_10_07/DJI_005701_zing.jpeg

​https://znews-photo.zadn.vn/Uploaded/lerl/2017_10_07/DJI_005701_zing.jpeg

The first one should not be returned.

This is a job assignment from a web search team, therefore I care a lot about performance.

My current approach:

*) To avoid trivial names, iterate through the testing queries for image search, count the number of appearance of each token from different URLs after tokenized by "/", and manually pick the most appeared tokens in the URLs which are similar to "photo", "picture", "background", etc... In the end, I will have a set of trivial names.

*) For pictures with the same name, each picture I get its [dHash](http://tech.jetsetter.com/2017/03/21/duplicate-image-detection/), its resolution, for every pair of pictures with dHash difference less than a certain thresh hold, I discard the picture with smaller resolution.

Edit: After consulted with my manager, I realized that I misunderstood the requirements. I should only work purely on the URLs without accessing to the actual images (which would be too expensive). With the example above, I should be able to discard the first image based on the URLs difference of the two. Also, as the result, expecting accuracy isn't high, anything > 85% should be decent.

I greatly appreciate any ideas/insights on improving my current approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to implement robust solution to this problem without accessing image contents. However, if you still want to work directly with URLs, here are some observations:

1. Original images often contain "orig" or "original" keywords in their urls, while thumbnails contain "thumb" or "thumbnails" keywords
2. URLs for thumbnails often contain width and height numbers (e.g. 640, 768, 1024)
3. Generally, longer URL (from the same host) means a thumbnail. This is because when thumbnail is generated, width/height numbers usually are appended to its name.

Entirely different approach is to retrieve image byte sizes by issuing HTTP HEAD requests. In 99% cases server will return `Content-Length` header. HTTP HEAD doesn't download contents, only the HTTP headers. As such, it is not so expensive as downloading entire images.